# How to move qt4_wrap_cpp output to a folder?

Tags: qt, cmake

I have made a call to `qt4_wrap_cpp(moc_outfiles ${moc_header})` and I want the results of that call (`moc_outfiles`) to be placed in a folder called `GeneratedFiles/Debug`.

So far what I tried to make my own custom method that failed due to parsing error `Parse error.  Expected "(", got quoted argument with text "${it}".`

```
FOREACH (it ${moc_headers})
    QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE ${it} -o ./GeneratedFiles/Debug/moc_"${it}"
ENDFOREACH(it)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) command.  Also, you probably don't want the quotes round `${it}` in your output filename:

```
FOREACH(it ${moc_headers})
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE} ${it} -o ./GeneratedFiles/Debug/moc_${it})
ENDFOREACH(it)
```

You may need to add the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument too - I'm unfamiliar with Qt's moc exe.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I may not understand how CMake work. Is it after I run the CMake script and run the project the files should be generated?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `qt4_wrap_cpp` you could use the `qt4_generate_moc` macro, which takes a single file to be moced and an output path. With this macro you can construct something similar to what `qt4_wrap_cpp` does.

```
#qt4_wrap_cpp( moc_outfiles ${moc_headers} )
foreach(moc_hdr ${moc_headers})
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(moc_name ${moc_hdr} NAME_WE)
  SET (moc_out ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/GeneratedFiles/moc_${moc_name}.cxx)
  QT4_GENERATE_MOC( ${moc_in} ${moc_out} )
  LIST (APPEND MOC_SOURCES ${moc_out})
endforeach(moc_hdr)
```